# how to return all value in pivot table in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, model, laravel-5.4

i got pivot table that consist of
account_id
article_id
created_at
updated_at

how to retrieve all of them in View. I have 2 model account and article

```
class Account extends Model
{
    public function articles()
    {
         return $this->belongsToMany('App\Article','accountsarticles')->withPivot('account_id','article_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}

class Article extends Model
{
    public function accounts()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Account','accountsarticles')->withPivot('account_id','article_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

And also i have controller like this

```
class AccountsArticlesController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        /*If i use this 1 i can get all of column data*/
        $accountsarticles=DB::table('accountsarticles')->get();

        /*If i use this 1 i only get created_at and updated_at*/
        $acc = Account::all();
        return view('accountsarticles.index',['accountsarticles'=>$accountsarticles]);
    }
}
```

For now i retrieve it like this without using MVC

```
@foreach($accountsarticles as $article)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$article->created_at}}</td>
        <td>{{$article->updated_at}}</td>
        <td>{{$article->account_id}}</td>
        <td>{{$article->article_id}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

I wondering how to retrieve all column in that pivot so i can show all data in that column when the view returned.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following syntax `$model->pivot->field_name`

In your case, it'll be:

```
//to fetch account id
$article->pivot->account_id

//to fetch article id
$article->pivot->article_id
```

Comment: i already try that but it give me "Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: You are not sending collection of models in your view. You are using `DB` to fetch data from table name only `$accountsarticles=DB::table('accountsarticles')->get()` that's why it is giving error.

Comment: @Student send `$acc = Account::all()` data to the view.

Comment: I already change to $acc, but not returned the account_id and article_id. even i already use pivot->field_name.
Only created_at and updated_at that returned

Comment: What are you trying to display in view ? Articles of a particular account ? @Student